# Elements not recognised in a webpage- Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a flight from the choose flight page but Selenium is not able to locate any element on the page. I did try using different element locators but it still doesn't work. Can you help please?

```
public class Cal_AA {
static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, InterruptedException {


    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.get("https://www.americanairlines.ie/intl/ie/index.jsp?locale=en_IE");

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bookingModule']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/label/span[2]")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reservationFlightSearchForm.originAirport']")).sendKeys("LHR");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reservationFlightSearchForm.destinationAirport']")).sendKeys("DFW");

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='aa-leavingOn']")).click();
     selectDate("12/06/2017");

}


public static void selectDate(String date) throws ParseException, InterruptedException{

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      Date dateToBeSelected = df.parse(date);
      Date currentDate = new Date();
      String monthYearDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/div")).getText();

      System.out.println("month year displayed " + monthYearDisplayed);
      String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(dateToBeSelected);
      String year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(dateToBeSelected);
      String day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(dateToBeSelected);
      String monthYearToBeSelected=month+ " "+year;
      System.out.println(monthYearToBeSelected);


      while(true){
    if (monthYearToBeSelected.equals(monthYearDisplayed)) {
              //select date
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='"+day+"']")).click();
               System.out.println("Found and Selected");
              break;

      }else{//if you are not in the right month & year, you have to then navigate to the right month & year

          if(dateToBeSelected.after(currentDate)){


              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]/div/a")).click();//click fowardicon 

          }else{
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/a")).click();//click backicon
          }

      }
    monthYearDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/div")).getText();
}



    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bookingModule-submit']")).click();

    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='table-bound0-column0']")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id='table-bound0-column0']")).click();

    Thread.sleep(5000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tpl3_table-bound0-cell00-available']")).click();

    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id='tpl3_table-bound0-cell00-available']")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.id("tpl3_table-bound0-cell01-available")).click();

    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

    //WebElement tpl3 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("tpl3_table-bound0-cell01-available")));
    //tpl3.click();



} 



}
```

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementException occurs if I find an element, the DOM gets updated then I try to interact with the element.f Javascript updates the page between the findElement call and the click call then I'll get a StaleElementException. It is not uncommon for this to occur on modern web pages. It will not happen consistently however. The timing has to be just right for this bug to occur.

The following code will work for you

public class Cal_AA {

```
static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.americanairlines.ie/intl/ie/index.jsp?locale=en_IE");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bookingModule']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/label/span[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reservationFlightSearchForm.originAirport']")).sendKeys("LHR");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reservationFlightSearchForm.destinationAirport']")).sendKeys("DFW");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='aa-leavingOn']")).click();
    selectDate("12/06/2017");

}


public static void selectDate(String date) throws Exception{

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dateToBeSelected = df.parse(date);
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    String monthYearDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/div")).getText();

    System.out.println("month year displayed " + monthYearDisplayed);
    String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(dateToBeSelected);
    String year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(dateToBeSelected);
    String day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(dateToBeSelected);
    String monthYearToBeSelected=month+ " "+year;
    System.out.println(monthYearToBeSelected);


    while(true){
        if (monthYearToBeSelected.equals(monthYearDisplayed)) {
            //select date
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='"+day+"']")).click();
            System.out.println("Found and Selected");
            break;

        }else{//if you are not in the right month & year, you have to then navigate to the right month & year

            if(dateToBeSelected.after(currentDate)){


                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]/div/a")).click();//click fowardicon 

            }else{
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/a")).click();//click backicon
            }

        }
        monthYearDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/div")).getText();
    }



    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bookingModule-submit']")).click();

    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='table-bound0-column0']")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id='table-bound0-column0']")).click();

    Thread.sleep(20000);

    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 4) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='availability-container row']/descendant::div[contains(@id,'table-bound0-cell00-available-content')][1]")).click();
            System.out.println("CLICKED !!");
            break;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION OCCURED..RETRY !!");
        }
        attempts++;
    }


    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id='tpl3_table-bound0-cell00-available']")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.id("tpl3_table-bound0-cell01-available")).click();

    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

    //WebElement tpl3 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("tpl3_table-bound0-cell01-available")));
    //tpl3.click();



}
```

}

Comment: Hi Shubham, This worked well. Thank you very much. Please can you throw more light on how you derived the xpath used above.

Comment: Hi Shubham Mathur, i am writting a script where Selenium should click on any available cell randomly. Please how do i construct the xpath to cater for all available cells?